# Conditions to stop Plotly live Graph

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I was wondering if it was possible to stop a live graph created with Plotly.
Here is my script

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from threading import Timer
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from flask import request
from collections import deque
import webbrowser
import os
import time

X1, Y1 = [1], [1.0]
X2, Y2 = [1], [1.0]
X3, Y3 = [1], [1.0]
X4, Y4 = [1], [1.0]

port = 8050
host = '127.0.0.1'
url = f'http://{host}:{str(port)}/'

def build_dash_app():
    app = dash.Dash(__name__)

    app.layout = html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True, style={"height": "97vh", 'width': "97vw"}),
            dcc.Interval(
                id='graph-update',
                interval=1000, # milliseconds
                n_intervals=0
            ),
        ]
    )

    @app.callback(
        Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
        [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')],
        log=True
    )
    def update_graph_scatter(n):
        print(f"{n=}")
        fig = plot_graph()
        return fig

    return app


def plot_graph():
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=['1', '2', '3', '4'])

    X1.append(X1[-1] + 1)
    Y1.append(Y1[-1] + Y1[-1] * random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1))

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=list(X1),
        y=list(Y1),
        name='Scatter1',
        mode='lines+markers'
    ), col=1, row=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(col=1, row=1, range=[min(X1), max(X1)])
    fig.update_yaxes(col=1, row=1, range=[min(Y1), max(Y1)])

    X2.append(X2[-1] + 1)
    Y2.append(Y2[-1] + Y2[-1] * random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1))

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=list(X2),
        y=list(Y2),
        name='Scatter2',
        mode='lines+markers'
    ), col=2, row=1)

    fig.update_xaxes(col=2, row=1, range=[min(X2), max(X2)])
    fig.update_yaxes(col=2, row=1, range=[min(Y2), max(Y2)])

    X3.append(X3[-1] + 1)
    Y3.append(Y3[-1] + Y3[-1] * random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1))

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=list(X3),
        y=list(Y3),
        name='Scatter3',
        mode='lines+markers'
    ), col=1, row=2)
    fig.update_xaxes(col=1, row=2, range=[min(X3), max(X3)])
    fig.update_yaxes(col=1, row=2, range=[min(Y3), max(Y3)])

    X4.append(X4[-1] + 1)
    Y4.append(Y4[-1] + Y4[-1] * random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1))

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=list(X4),
        y=list(Y4),
        name='Scatter4',
        mode='lines+markers'
    ), col=2, row=2)

    fig.update_xaxes(col=2, row=2, range=[min(X4), max(X4)])
    fig.update_yaxes(col=2, row=2, range=[min(Y4), max(Y4)])
    fig.write_html("fig1.html")
    return fig


def open_browser():
    if not os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN"):
        webbrowser.open_new(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Hello")
    Timer(1, open_browser).start()
    app = build_dash_app()
    app.run_server(port=8050, debug=True)
    print("World")
```

What I want the script to do is :

1. `print ("Hello")`
2. open the live graph on the browser
3. when `len(X1)==100`, stop the live graph
4. `print("World")`

I don't know how to do step 3.

I've seen that you can shut the server by adding

```
def shutdown_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()
```

and

```
    @app.server.route('/shutdown', methods=['POST'])
    def shutdown():
        shutdown_server()
        return 'Server shutting down...'
```

But I did not understand how to use it.
And I've seen that in the `app.layout`, you can add a `max_intervals`

```
    app.layout = html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True, style={"height": "97vh", 'width': "97vw"}),
            dcc.Interval(
                id='graph-update',
                interval=1000, # milliseconds
                n_intervals=0,
                max_intervals=100
            ),
        ]
    )
```

However, `n` follows the time and not the number of steps executed.

Answer (score 1):

You could target the `disabled` prop of your interval component

> disabled (boolean; optional): If True, the counter will no longer update.

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval

So you could change your callback to something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('graph-update', 'disabled'),
    Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
    Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals'),
    log=True
)
def update_graph_scatter(n):
    graph_updates_disabled = False

    print(f"{n=}")
    fig = plot_graph()

    if len(X1) >= 100:
        graph_updates_disabled = True

    return graph_updates_disabled, fig
```

Comment: I was able to stop the cript with your solution, thanks. However, the script doesn't continue. I have this : ```Hello
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 * Serving Flask app 'Live_plot_Errors'
 * Debug mode: on
Hello```
.
`Hello` is repeated twice and `World` is not printed.

Comment: `World` is not printed because you try to run it after `app.run_server(port=8050, debug=True)`. run_server finishes only when you decide to stop the app. So it will never reach past that point. Hello being ran twice is probably due to debug being set to True. It is not an actual issue, your app has not stopped. If you added another check in your callback and set `graph_updates_disabled ` to false again when `len(X1) >= 110` for example, you would see the updates continue again.

Comment: So it's not possible to run script after app.run_server? What I want is to do some actions after the graph is done being plot.

Comment: Correct. Maybe you could do it in some convoluted way, but I wouldn't recommend it. I recommend doing it using callbacks. You could use your `live-graph` figure property for example to know when the figure is updated. So you could create a callback with an input like this: `Input('live-graph', 'figure')`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to Bas van der Linden's solution to stop the graph and added Threading and it does almost what I want to do.

What the script does :

1. `print("Hello")`
2. Open a live graph on the browser
3. when `len(X1)==20`, stop the live graph
4. `print("World")`

I said almost because I used a Thread to run the `app.run_server`. However I was not able to stop the server. And even if I stop the thread at the end, I think the server is still active.

Here is my solution :

```
import dash
import requests
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from threading import Timer, Thread, Event
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from flask import request
from collections import deque
import webbrowser
import os
import time
from flask import Flask


X1, Y1 = [1], [1.0]
X2, Y2 = [1], [1.0]
X3, Y3 = [1], [1.0]
X4, Y4 = [1], [1.0]

port = 5000
host = '127.0.0.1'
url = f'http://{host}:{str(port)}/'
keepPlot = True


def build_dash_app():
    server = Flask(__name__)
    app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)

    app.layout = html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True, style={"height": "97vh", 'width': "97vw"}),
            dcc.Interval(
                id='graph-update',
                interval=1000, # milliseconds
                n_intervals=0,
            ),
        ]
    )

    @app.callback(
        Output('graph-update', 'disabled'),
        Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
        Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals'),
    )
    def update_graph_scatter(n):
        global keepPlot
        graph_updates_disabled = False

        fig = plot_graph() if keepPlot else None

        if len(X1) >= 20:
            graph_updates_disabled = True
            keepPlot = False
            # shutdown_server()

        return graph_updates_disabled, fig

    return app


def plot_graph():
    """ return a plotly fig"""
    return fig


def app_run_server(debug):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
    app = build_dash_app()
    app.run_server(port=port, debug=debug, use_reloader=False)


class MyThread(Thread):

    # Thread class with a _stop() method.
    # The thread itself has to check
    # regularly for the stopped() condition.

    def __init__(self, target, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(target=target, *args, **kwargs)
        self._stop = Event()

    # function using _stop function
    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Hello")
    dash_thread = MyThread(target=app_run_server, args=(True,))
    dash_thread.start()

    while keepPlot:
        time.sleep(1)  # keep the main thread alive while the other threads are running

    print("World")
    dash_thread.stop()
    print("!")
```